# OpenGL ES 1.1 vs 2.0 for 2D Graphics, with rotated sprites?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am having trouble finding information related to which i should choose, OpenGL ES 1.1 or 2.0 for 2D graphics.

OpenGL ES 1.1 on Android is a bit limited to my knowledge, and based purely on sprite count the only useful renderer is draw_texture() *(as far as i know)*. However, that does not have rotation and rotation is very important to me.

Now with the NDK adding support for OpenGL ES 2.0, i am trying to figure out if there is anything that preforms as well as draw_texture(), but can handle rotation.

Anyone have any information on if 2.0 can help me in this area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenGL ES 2.0 will not be of much more help than OpenGL ES 1.1. Can't you just draw your sprites using textured quads?

Comment: I am just now getting back to this (had some side web projects for the last 2 months) but my "information" is mostly coming from a Google talk done on Gaming, where a sprite renderer was made (and released) to test the multiple methods of rendering. draw_texture appeared to be far, near twice, as fast as the next closest (VBO, iirc) method for rendering sprites.

Though, if 2.0 won't help in this area i simply may have to dump draw_texture for any of my rotation needs.

Comment: well if quads are too slow in general, you may still be able to use them or some other slow method to do the actual rotation, then cache the result and use it with draw_texture on subsequent frames.  That way you only pay once.

Answer (score 1):

What hardware?

Whether textured quads and the modelview matrix multiplies are hardware accelerated (hence fast) depends on your hardware and drivers, not your OS or OpenGL ES version.

Comment: Hardware? No idea. Any 2.0+ Android Operating system, but i am not targeting a single phone, nor do i want to target a slim margin of phones with one specific hardware advantage over another.

Are all the more recent phones being implemented hardware acceleration?

Comment: The newest ARM SOCs from TI, Motorola, and Qualcomm all have hardware accelerated 2D graphics.  I don't know how that translates into current phone sales or existing phones.